# go template - nested templated

Tags: go, go-templates

I have several go templates. The below examples are oversimplified, but it states my idea correctly. For example, I have

```
{{ define "div-block" }}
   <div style="display:block">
         .....
   </div>
{{ end }}
```

Now I want to transfer any other template inside `div-block` when using it, so that I could put anything inside div. E.g:

```
{{ template "div-block" . }}
    {{ template "header" }}
{{ end }}

{{ template "div-block" . }}
    <ul>
       <li>1</li>
    </ul>
{{ end }}
```

Where "header" is some other template.

Which is the the right way to do this with go template? Is it possible to do it with custom function? Is it possible to make custom `actions` in go template? (actions can have `end`  statement and therefore the body, while functions are not)

Comment: How about split the `div-block` into open and end tag? Like `{{ template "div-begin" . }} something {{template "div-end" . }}`?

Comment: This is a good point, thank you. However, question is still open in case there can be more variants

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested template in go template.

```
divBlock := `<div>Hello div
                {{block "header" .}} {{.}} {{end}}
             </div>`
header := `<header>Hello Header</header>`

divTempl, err := template.New("master").Parse(divBlock)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := divTempl.Execute(os.Stdout, header); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Go-playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/K36l3bn5753

Or

You can use if statement. Check whether there is some template, then append, otherwise empty.

```
const (
    divBlock = `<div style="display:block">
                 .....
            {{if "injectedTmpl"}}{{.}}{{end}}
           </div>`
)   
injectedTmpl := `<header>Hello Header</header>`

divTmpl, err := template.New("div").Parse(divBlock)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := divTmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, injectedTmpl); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Go-playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/pZaqXtCHHAL

Answer (score 0):

define another template outside, and use it inside div-block template